# how to run batch queries in sql ce?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

for example:

```
  StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> key in list)
                    {
                        string name = key.Key;
                        string emails = key.Value;
                        query.AppendFormat("insert into contacts(name, emails) values('{0}', '{1}');", name, emails);
                    }

   string queries = query.ToString(); //how to run it?
```

it is possible?

Comment: Slightly misleading title I think... Are you wanting to Batch insert a list of things, or get multiple datasets from a series of selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to begin a transaction before the loop, execute each statement rather than adding it to stringbuilder, and commit after the loop (or every n number of records).

Also, you should use a parameterized command, something along the lines of:

```
SqlCeCommand oCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
oCommand.CommandText = "insert into contacts(name, emails) values(?, ?)";
// I can't remember if the param names need @ or not
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
oCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);

SqlCeTransaction oTrans = conn.BeginTransaction();
try {
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> key in list) {
     oCommand.Parameters[0].Value = key.Key;
     oCommand.Parameters[1].Value = key.Value;
     oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  oTrans.Commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  oTrans.Rollback();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [SQL Compact Bulk Insert Library](http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/) from codeplex. I believe that this uses a TableDirect SqlCeCommand on top of a SqlCeResultSet, which should bypass the query processor and be about as fast as you can get.

Comment: hum,I did it, I'm looking for an alternative to this.

Comment: Updated with additional option.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported feature in V3.5 of the compact edition.  Not sure if it changed in V4.

The opening of a connection/transaction and looping is your only option really.

Sorry it's bad news!

Comment: It didn't change. It's still unsupported.